# How to display array elements with jquery jsform

Tags: jquery, jsform

I am trying to use [JSForm](https://github.com/corinis/jsForm/) for display an edit JSON data!

In the [Samples](https://github.com/corinis/jsForm/wiki/JsForm-Dom-Layout#collections) I see how to display a array with "nested objects" like

```
[
  {href:'http://www.gargan.org',description:'Gargan.org'},
  {href:'http://www.github.com',description:'GitHub'}
]
```

and I can fetch it with

```
<ul class="collection" data-field="data.links">
  <li><span class="field">links.description</span> 
  Link: <input name="links.href"/></li>
</ul>
```

But now I got a "pure" Array like

```
[2500,5000,9000,12500,25000,50000]
```

How do I get the values of this array?

**UPDATE** The developer updated his code! In about a hour... Have a look a the latest commit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the control to include the feature.

the correct syntax for an array like:

```
    { "quips":["some", "array"] }
```

the html should look like:

```
    <ul class="collection" data-field="data.quips">
        <li><input name="quips."/></li>
    </ul>
```

basically the same as zaheer had - you jsut need to add a "." to note that it is the field itself.

Answer (score 0):

As it is simple array you don`t need selector now:

```
<ul class="collection" data-field="data.links">
  <li><span class="field">links</span> 
</ul>
```